# Docker swarm service log output stopped

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

For a docker swarm service that is running, when I execute `docker service logs [service name] -f`, I see that the service has stopped showing logs. I have to restart the service to start the logs to be printed out to the stdout again. What could be a reason for this?

Comment: Your disk could be full perhaps, or your docker user is over quota?

Comment: I'm hosting the container on a server with enough disk space. Any other possibilities?